# Multi-line pattern in FileBeat

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana, filebeat

I am using Filbeat for log aggregation, which takes the logs to Kibana. Below is my error message that needs to be directed to Kibana:

```
    2017-04-17 15:45:47,154 [JCO.ServerThread-8] ERROR com.webservice.AxisWebServiceClient - Client error
    2017-04-17 15:45:47,154 [JCO.ServerThread-8] ERROR com.webservice.AxisWebServiceClient - The XML request is invalid. Fix the request and resend.
310,273,990
310,292,500
360,616,489
    2017-04-04 12:47:09,362 [JCO.ServerThread-3] INFO  com.app.Listener - End RFC_CALCULATE_TAXES_DOC
    2017-04-04 12:47:09,362 [JCO.ServerThread-3] DEBUG com.Time - RFC_CALCULATE_TAXES_DOC,DEC[2],Total Time,39
```

i want only to have **2017-04-17 15:45:47,154 [JCO.ServerThread-8]ERROR** and lines below the error to be send to Kibana, but i do get the INFO part as well

Below is filbeat.yml file

```
filebeat:
  prospectors:
    -
      paths:
       - /apps/global/vertex/SIC_HOME_XEC/logs/sic.log
      input_type: log
      exclude_lines: ['^INFO']
      #include_lines: 'ERROR'
      multiline:
        pattern: '^\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}\s\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2},\d{3}\s\[[A-Za-z0-9.-]*\]\s[E]RROR'
        negate: true
        match: after
```

Request veterans help to select only the ERROR message pattern using regex.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In order to extract the error messages as a group, you'll need to modify your regex as following:

```
^\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}\s\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2},\d{3}\s\[[A-Za-z0-9.-]*\]\sERROR (\w.+)
```

Explanation:

```
(\w.+)
```

This creates a group with all characters and the dot character, which captures the error message.